# Read data from Firebase Database failed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with an android app, I can't set a textView with a String in the Firebase Database. I would to set the text of TextView with a string in my JSON.

```
mDatabaseReference.child("Profilo").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                UserProfile mProfile = dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserProfile.class);
                nomeProfilo.setText(mProfile.getNome());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }@Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

this is my Logcat

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.mysecurity.marco.mysecurty.UserProfile
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source:89)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source:145)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
                                                                                at com.mysecurity.marco.mysecurty.MaterialUserActivity$3.onChildAdded(MaterialUserActivity.java:194)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbox.zza(Unknown Source:33)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source:63)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Not really clear why you are setting the content of a single TextView within a loop. That should be the first sign you've done something wrong

Comment: I want to set Name and Surname of my user in the textView of Navigation Header, but also without for code do not fill out

Comment: Sure, but you're getting every inner key of the object. Not the object as a whole. As your error says, you're mapping a string key to an object

Comment: Check your UserProfile class for these two conditions:
1. The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments

2.The class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their default value when an instance is deserialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 mDatabaseReference.child("Profilo").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {//to retrieve data
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
              String names=dataSnapshot1.child("nome").getValue().toString();
              nomeProfilo.setText(names);


                }
           }
         @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

or you can do this also to prevent from iterating using the loop:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
mDatabaseReference.child("Profilo").child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      String names=dataSnapshot1.child("nome").getValue().toString();
              nomeProfilo.setText(names);


                }
           }
         @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
   });
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but now Logcat says that  'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: @Marco Because the TextView is null. That error is unrelated to Firebase

Comment: @Marco try the above and show your database, I changed it completely to addListenerForSingleValueEvent (better to read once in this case)

Comment: I posted a tree screen, maybe it is better to adopt the solution with a single value

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first answer with `getValue(UserProfile.class)` was correct @Peter   Your solutions here won't fix the nullpointerexception on the TextView

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I know it should have been correct, but I'm debugging the answer with him now lol

Comment: I tried with the solution of Peter, but the Logcat remians :  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: @Marco which of the two above did u try? In the second one change this `String names=dataSnapshot1.child("nome").getValue().toString();` **to this:** `String names=dataSnapshot.child("nome").getValue().toString();`

Comment: I had noticed the changeover but in both the logCat does not change

Comment: well have u initialized the textview before this? What is `mDatabaseReference` equal to?

Comment: mDatabaseReference = mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users").child(mUser.getUid());

Comment: the id above `Profilo` is a userid, and the id below `Profilo` is also a userid?? That's wrong.. @Marco

Comment: @Marco the above two solutions have to work, and the one before the edit also. But check the mDatabaseReference as it may be wrong and also check if u initialized everything example the `textview`

Comment: @Marco please upvote the answer and mark it as correct so it can help others also, thank you! – Peter Haddad

Answer (score 1):

The data in the NoSQL database is is in the JSON form. So from your original code:

```
for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(child.getValue(String.class));
    nomoProfilo.setText(json.getString("nome");
}
```

You can build your UserProfile object from the fields of the json.

Comment: Does that work with Firebase? Using `getValue(UserProfile.class);` is the documented, correct way to get an object. Just because Firebase is NoSQL doesn't mean that objects are actually JSON

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree
UserProfile is not a Firebase user class that I can find, the Android SDK class is UserInfo unless I am missing something in a big way (not impossible). My code works with firebase, yes. It's from a Firebase app that is working.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a Firebase class... It's a POJO that the OP created. See here with the Post class https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: Then the class needs to be posted because the error would indicate that the class structure does not meet the criteria specified by the getValue(class<T>) method being used. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class<T>)

Comment: I agree, and that should be added as a comment above.